# Plotting a scatterplot with two continous variables but generating 'Discrete value supplied to continuous scale error' -updated

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a scatterplot with continuous variables on both the x and y axis

Here is a simulation that pretty accurately represents what the data would look like (there's a couple of vectors with data items that are integers in the real thing, but that's immaterial here)

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(243)
DemoDataTable <- tibble(Treatment = rep(c(0, 1), times = 20), ## each column is repeated 20 times, not 20 times for both
                        CorrectAnswers = rnorm(40, 1, 2),
                        Age = rnorm(40, 20, 5),
                        PositiveAffect = rnorm(40, 1.5, 1),
                        NegativeAffect = rnorm(40, 2, 1),
                        TreatmentExpectancy = rnorm(40, 2, 1)) %>% 
  mutate(Treatment = as.factor(Treatment))
```

Positive affect = 'positive affect2', negative affect = 'negative affect2' in the code below

I am aware there are some NaN items in the x and y variables, but have attempted to remove them, the rest are continuous data on both axes. Have also checked the data frame using the glimpse function, only Treatment as a variable is showing up as a factor, the rest are coded as 'double', which to my understanding means numeric data.

The code:

```
ggplot(Data object, aes(x = 'Negative affect2', y = 'Positive affect2'), na.rm = TRUE) + 
  geom_point(colour = "blue") +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Negative affect") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Positive affect") +
  theme_minimal()
```

However when I attempt to run the code, it states the error message: 'Discrete value supplied to continuous scale'

I have also tried to use the na.omit function in place of na.rm but this has made no difference

EDIT:

I have changed the column names from "Negative Affect2" and "Positive Affect2" to "NegativeAffect" and "PositiveAffect" but this has made no difference to the error

I have found that when running the code for the scatterplot line by line (as per below), I immediately hit problems when I get to line 2 as it will only give me a single data point on the x and y axes (whether I insert na.rm = T or not).

```
ggplot(RTdataset2, aes(x = "NegativeAffect", y = "PositiveAffect", na.rm = T)) + 
  geom_point(colour = "blue")
```

However, I have not used the summarise function from dyplr at any point so not sure why this is, as it should plot all the data points from the sample against each other. I believe this is where the problem arises, as otherwise it would not state that I am trying to apply a discrete variable to a continuous scale as per below that.

Comment: Try with backticks "`" instead of quotes around your variable names.

Comment: Don't use quotes while referring to column names in `aes`. If you have spaces in column name refer them with backticks (`\`column name\``) as @stefan suggested.

Comment: Thanks, that has worked :) - will make a note of that going forward